# Python Openpyxl can't find number in xlsx

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

Python 3.7.1

I have an excel which looks like something like this

[xls example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkYLy.jpg)

With my script I would like to find the row where is "222" located and update this line. I write a script which can find that kind of row but only that case if the cell contains text.

The script:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
issue = "222"
path = "\\.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(path)

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
for row in ws.iter_rows():
   for cell in row:
       if cell.value == issue:
           print (cell.coordinate)
```

Outcome:

- If the cell contain numbers the result is nothing. There is no error and nothing
- If the cell contains text then the script print out the
  cell number (B3)

The problem in my case that the cells are only contains numbers. I already searched on the web but didn't find any solution why the script don't find number in my xls.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem looks to be line 2: `issue = "222"`. You defined issue as a string containing the numbers 222. Instead just change that to `issue = 222` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hey @denes, glad I could help! Please mark the answer as accepted so people know your question was solved (tick the little box below up and downvote buttons).